# Using Palatino font with groff mom macros

Tags: text-processing, fonts, groff

I am trying to use the Palatino font with my [groff mom](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_mom.7.html) document.

The [documentation](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/typesetting.html#family) says

> FAMILY takes one argument: the name of the family you want. Groff comes with a small set of basic families, each identified by a 1-, 2-or 3-letter mnemonic. The standard families are:
> A   = Avant Garde
> BM  = Bookman
> H   = Helvetica
> HN  = Helvetica Narrow
> N   = New Century Schoolbook
> P   = Palatino
> T   = Times Roman
> ZCM = Zapf Chancery
> The argument you pass to FAMILY is the identifier at left, above. For example, if you want Helvetica, enter
> .FAMILY H

I assume then that I can use the Palatino font with `.FAMILY P`. However, when I do this I get these warnings, and the compiled PDF uses a fallback monospace font:

```
report.mom:28: warning: can't find font `PR'
report.mom:31: warning: can't find font `PB'
report.mom:31: warning: can't find font `PI'
report.mom:31: warning: can't find font `PBI'
[mom]: Either font style "B" at line 31 does not exist in family "P",
       or family "P" has not been installed.
Aborting 'report.mom' at FT, line 31.
```

I am compiling like this:

```bsh
pdfmom -t report.mom > report.pdf
```

I have groff version 1.22.3 installed.

My interpretation of "Groff comes with a small set of basic families" is that all of the standard families are available in the default installation of groff.

Am I mistaken? Is there a manual step I need to take to install or configure Palatino for use by groff?

**Edit**

Looking more closely on my system:

```
$ ls /usr/share/groff/1.22.3/font/devpdf
CB   CI  DESC      enc   Foundry  HBI  HR   S   TBI  TR    ZD
CBI  CR  download  EURO  HB       HI   map  TB  TI   util
$ ls /usr/share/groff/1.22.3/font/devps
AB   BMB   CB   DESC          freeeuro.pfa  HI    HNR  NI   PI        SS            text.enc    ZCMI
ABI  BMBI  CBI  download      generate      HNB   HR   NR   PR        symbolsl.pfa  TI          ZD
AI   BMI   CI   EURO          HB            HNBI  NB   PB   prologue  TB            TR          ZDR
AR   BMR   CR   freeeuro.afm  HBI           HNI   NBI  PBI  S         TBI           zapfdr.pfa
```

So it appears I have Palantino available for the `ps` device (because of the `P*` files in `font/devps`) but not for the `pdf` device.

I tried to just copy the `P*` files from `font/devps` to `font/devpdf` and recompile, but then the text had weird spacing issues after. There are no spacing issues if I compile with `-Tps`.

How can I correctly configure my system to allow me to use the Palantino font with the `pdf` device?

Comment: The needed file may be in a separate package. Eg on my old Fedora system, the file `/usr/share/groff/1.22.3/font/devpdf/PBI` is in package `groff-perl`, whereas `groff-base` contains all the `.../devps/` metrics files.

Comment: @meuh I'm on Ubuntu, and there doesn't appear to be a `groff-perl` `apt` package, unless its part of a PPA I don't have. I have both the `groff` and `groff-base` `apt` packages installed (both are version 1.22.3).

Comment: Copying the font metrics is enough to create the pdf but to view it you also need the actual Palatino font available to the pdf viewer. As it is probably copyright and non-free it might not be available on Unix systems.

Comment: I'm using evince as my PDF viewer. When I compile to PostScript with `groff -mom -Tps -t report.mom > report.ps` and view the PS file in evince, the text doesn't have any spacing issues. When I copy the `P*` files to `font/devpdf` and compile to PDF with `pdfmom -t report.mom > report.pdf`, then the text has spacing issues in PDF. So I believe just copying the `font/devps/P*` files to `font/devpdf` is not the right solution.

Comment: @ShaneBishop That's strange the Palatino font's not there. I've got it with Groff 1.22.4 on Debian in ```font/devpdf```. Try upgrading Groff?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the regular Troff `.fam` argument, then P. I've had pretty good success with that.

The other thing you can try is using Troff by itself and then the Postprocessor Gropdf to render like this.

```
troff -mom -Tpdf $INPUTFILE | gropdf $INPUTFILE > $OUTPUTFILE
```

(replace `$INPUTFILE` with your File name and `$OUTPUTFILE` with what you want the PDF called)